# Stablearrayadapter context on dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-arrayadapter

I am using a stablearrayadapter in another activity (which works perfectly). Trying to get it to work on a dialog fragment.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: eu.lunca.santa, PID: 22179
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at eu.lunca.santa.SearchDialog.listit(SearchDialog.java:98)
        at eu.lunca.santa.SearchDialog.onCreateDialog(SearchDialog.java:62)
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:308)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Now from my understanding the problem is that there is some null object in the arguments for setadapter.

```
private void listit(){
    final ListView listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listBooks);



    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); ++i) {
        list.add(ll.get(i));
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list); //A: Think problem is here

    listview.setAdapter(adapter); //B: Where it crashes

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Touch: " + position);
            switch (position){
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now I have tried printing all the arguments in the stablearraadapter, and none are empty. If the problem is the first element (context), I've tried a lot of things (getactivity(), getcontext(), getactivity().getbasecontext(), etc.)

Anyone that can help me figure out what the problem is?

The whole dialog fragment (in case):

```
public class SearchDialog extends DialogFragment {

private DBAdapter db;
private LinkedList<String> ll;
private Singleton s;

//log
final String TAG = "TColorDialogFragment";

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    s = (Singleton) getActivity().getApplication();
    ll = new LinkedList<String>();
    db = new DBAdapter(getContext());
    cargarLibros();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setTitle(R.string.choosebook);
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            SearchDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
        }
    });

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_dialog, null);

    /*List stuff*/
    listit();

    return builder.create();
}

private void cargarLibros() {
    db.open();
    Cursor libros = db.getLibros();
    db.close();
    do {
        ll.add(libros.getString(1));
    } while (libros.moveToNext());
    //setListAdapter(new LibroAdapter(this, R.layout., ll)); //fix
}

private void listit(){
    final ListView listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listBooks);

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); ++i) {
        list.add(ll.get(i));
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Touch: " + position);
            switch (position){
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
}

private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

EDIT: The color_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listBooks"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: After you inflate the R.layout.color_dialog pass it to the listit() method and use it to search for the ListView instead of searching for the ListView through getActivity().

Comment: That helped in that now it doesn't crash. It doesn't show the list though... Thanks

Comment: Did you check to see if ll has some data in it after looking through the database?

Comment: Yes. list is an arraylist of 39 strings

Comment: Just to clear, the dialog is shown with no list on it? If you don't see the dialog you need to call the show() method on it in the activity.

Comment: This is how it looks: http://i.imgur.com/ka74Nal.png

Comment: Ok, you inflated that view but did you actually assign it as the content view of the dialog with: builder.setView(view);?

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Luksprog pointed out there are 2 mistakes:

1. Give listit() the view as an argument:

   listit(view);

and use it for the listview

```
private void listit(View view){
final ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listBooks);

...
```

2. I inflate the view but never actually assign it to the dialog:

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_dialog, null);

   /*List stuff*/

   listit();

   builder.setView(view);

   return builder.create();